# how can I select with multiple css selector with YUI3

Tags: yui, selector

```
<ul>
  <li class="selected cell">test</li>
  <li class="cell">test2</li>
</ul>
```

How can I select only the .selected .cell element?

Y.one('.selected, .cell') <= This selects boths li elements. and I just want to select the first

element.

Is there something like?
Y.one('.cell').one('.selected') ???

Answer (score 0):

```
.selected.cell
```

Notice the lack of space between them.